# mysql_fetch_assoc() error in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm running the following code, but everything it gives me the following errors. I've read several articles on SO, still no use. 
The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/xyz/public_html/13/beta/signup.php on line 49
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xyz/public_html/13/beta/signup.php:49) in /home/xyz/public_html/13/beta/signup.php on line 69
```

My `PHP` script:(I've marked the lines `49` & `69`)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    $err = array();
    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['pass'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $_POST['remember'] = (int)$_POST['remember'];

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,user,email,clg FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['pass'])."'"));-->line 49

        if($row['user'])
        {

            $_SESSION['user']=$row['user'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['clg'] = $row['clg'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];
            setcookie('tcookie',$_POST['remember']);
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);

    header("Location: signup.php");-->line 69
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Don't `md5()` something that has already been through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mysql_query` function is returning an error, instead of a result. Try:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id,user,email,clg FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['pass'])."'");
if ($res === false) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

This will help you get the error information.

Once that error is gone, you'll probably find that the 'headers already send error' disappears too, it's a consequence of something already being printed to the output (possibly an error message).

---

**Update**: For your 'No database selected' error, you need to use `mysql_select_db($databasename);` before you use `mysql_query()`. Otherwise, mysql has no idea which database you're trying to query.

Also, you may want to look into using PDO, it's another way of accessing MySQL databases, and it's heaps more secure and a bit easier to use (IMO).

Comment: you need to add `mysql_select_db($databasename);` before you use `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you executed mysql_connect properly and have a valid connection to a MySQL Server before doing mysql_query.
BTW, Fabian Tamp is right about PDO. Also mysqli extension is better then mysql. It is faster and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the espace after the colon in line 69.

Comment: There's nothing wrong a space between the header name and value.